# Variavel aparecendo como html - IONIC FRAMEWORK

Tags: angularjs, framework, ionic

Estou iniciando no Ionic, segui [este tutorial](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/08/make-http-requests-android-ios-ionicframework/), tudo certo ate entao, porem, quando vou no index.html e coloco a variavel {{firstname}}, no browser ele mostra como se estivesse passando por html, ao contrario ele tras escrito {{firstname}} e nao o data do array.

```
  <ion-content ng-controller="StudyingController">
  <button class="button" ng-click="getData()">Test</button>
  <br>
  name: {{firstname}} {{lastname}}
  </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode estar havendo algum erro na conexão com seu arquivo de dados, o "store", da sua aplicação, nesse caso seria importante nos exibir como você está fazendo a inclusão do seu arquivo de dados como está na aplicação que você está seguindo como exemplo:

```
$http.get("http://localhost/example.json", { params: { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" } })
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.firstname = data.firstname;
            $scope.lastname = data.lastname;
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Seguinte forma:

```
exampleApp.controller("StudyingController", function($scope, $http){

  $scope.getData = function(){
    $http.get("http://echo.jsontest.com/firstname/Nic/lastname/Raboy/state/California", { params: {"key1": "value", "key2": "value2"}})
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.firstname = data.firstname;
        $scope.lastname = data.lastname;
      })
      .error(function(data) {
        alert("PAAAAMM!!!!!!");

      })
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido galera,

o problema é que nao usei da seguinte forma:

exampleApp = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])

Vlw =D